# Verificar status do usuário ao realizar login

Tags: java, primefaces, xhtml, spring-security

Olá, pessoal. Estou com um problema ao formular minha tela de login e gostaria de pedir o conhecimento de vocês.

Estou usando o Eclipse Mars .1 para programar, O PrimeFaces para componentes visuais e o Spring Security para autenticação e autorização de usuários.

A situação é a seguinte: Na tela de login, estou pedindo para o usuário digitar o email e a senha para realizar login. O login só é efetuado quando as duas informações coincidem com as que estão no banco de dados. Até este ponto, tudo bem.
Mas no meu banco de dados existe um campo que se chama "status". Este campo é usado para indicar se o cadastro do usuário está em situação "ativo" ou "inativo".

Se o cadastro estiver com o status "inativo", mesmo que o email e a senha estejam corretas, não deve ser permitido que o usuário logue no sistema.
Estou com dificuldade para fazer este tratamento pelo campo "status".

Estou postando os códigos dos arquivos que acredito estarem relacionados com a autenticação do usuário no momento de fazer login.

**Login.xhtml**

Login

```
        <p:panel
             styleClass="grid-login">

            <p:graphicImage library="images" name="Rastrbov.png" />
            <h:panelGrid columns="2">
                <h:outputText value="Nome *" style="font-weight:bold;" />
                <p:inputText size="18" id="j_username" value="#{loginBean.nome}"
                    a:placeholder="&#128273;Usuario" />
                <h:outputText value="Senha *" style="font-weight:bold;" />
                <p:password size="18" id="j_password"
                    a:placeholder="&#128273;Senha" />
            </h:panelGrid>
            <h:panelGrid columns="4" width="100%" style="text-align:center">

                    <p:commandButton value="Entrar" action="#{loginBean.login}"
                        ajax="false" styleClass="botaoLogin" icon="ui-icon-circle-arrow-e"/>


                    <p:button value="Voltar" outcome="/Main.xhtml"
                        ajax="false" styleClass="botaoLogin" icon="ui-icon-home"/>
                    <br />


            </h:panelGrid>

                <h:panelGrid column="4" width="100%" style="text-align:center">
                        <h:panelGroup>
                            <p:commandLink style="text-decoration:underline;color:blue;"
                                value="Cadastre-se"
                                onclick="PF('varDialogCadastrarUsuario').show()" type="button" />
                            <br />
                            <p:commandLink style="text-decoration:underline;color:blue;"
                                value="Esqueci a senha"
                                onclick="PF('varDialogResetarSenha').show()" type="button" />
                        </h:panelGroup>
                </h:panelGrid>


        </p:panel>
    </h:form>
    <h:form>

        <p:dialog id="dialogResetarSenha" header="Recuperar Senha"
            widgetVar="varDialogResetarSenha" modal="true" showEffect="fade"
            resizable="false" hideEffect="fade">
            <p:panelGrid columns="1">

                <p:inputText value="#{usuarioLogadoMB.email}" required="true"
                    size="60" requiredMessage="O email é obrigatório"
                    id="emailRecuperaSenha" />
                <p:watermark value="Digite seu email" for="emailRecuperaSenha" />
            </p:panelGrid>
            <p:commandButton value="Enviar senha" icon="ui-icon-circle-check"
                actionListener="#{usuarioLogadoMB.solicitarNovaSenha}"
                oncomplete="if (!args.validationFailed){varDialogResetarSenha.hide()}" />
            <p:commandButton value="Cancelar" type="button"
                icon="ui-icon-circle-close" onclick="varDialogResetarSenha.hide()" />

        </p:dialog>
    </h:form>
    <h:form>

        <p:dialog id="dialogCadastrarUsuario" header="Cadastrar Usuario"
            widgetVar="varDialogCadastrarUsuario" modal="true" showEffect="fade"
            resizable="false" hideEffect="fade">
            <p:panelGrid columns="1">

                <p:inputText id="nome" size="60"
                    value="#{cadastroUsuarioTempBean.usuarioTemp.nome}" />
                <p:watermark value="Digite seu nome" for="nome" />



                <p:inputText id="email" size="60"
                    value="#{cadastroUsuarioTempBean.usuarioTemp.email}" />
                <p:watermark value="Digite seu email" for="email" />

                <p:password id="senha" size="60"
                    value="#{cadastroUsuarioTempBean.usuarioTemp.senha}" />
                <p:watermark value="Digite sua senha" for="senha" />

            </p:panelGrid>

            <p:commandButton value="Confirmar" icon="ui-icon-circle-check"
                actionListener="#{cadastroUsuarioTempBean.salvar}"
                oncomplete="PF('varDialogCadastrarUsuario').hide()" />

            <p:commandButton value="Cancelar" type="button"
                icon="ui-icon-circle-close"
                onclick="PF('varDialogCadastrarUsuario').hide()" />

        </p:dialog>
    </h:form>
</div>
```

**Usuario.java**

```
@Entity
@SequenceGenerator(name ="usuario_sequence", sequenceName = "usuario_sequence")
@Table(name = "usuario")
public class Usuario implements Serializable{


private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

private Long id;
private String nome;
private String senha;
private String status;
private String cpf;
private String rg;
private String email;
private String telefone;
private String celular;
private String endereco;
private Estado estado;
private Cidade cidade;
private String cep;
private List<Grupo> grupos = new ArrayList<>();

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "usuario_sequence")
public Long getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(Long id) {
    this.id = id;
}

@NotNull
@Column(nullable = false, length = 60)
public String getNome() {
    return nome;
}

public void setNome(String nome) {
    this.nome = nome;
}

@NotNull
@Column(nullable = false, length = 6)
public String getSenha() {
    return senha;
}

public void setSenha(String senha) {
    this.senha = senha;
}

@NotNull
@Column(nullable = false, length = 14, unique=true)
public String getCpf(){
    return cpf;
}

public void setCpf(String cpf){
    this.cpf = cpf;
}

@NotNull
@Column(nullable = false, length = 20)
public String getRg(){
    return rg;
}

public void setRg(String rg){
    this.rg = rg;
}

@NotNull
@Column(nullable = false, length = 50)
public String getEmail(){
    return email;
}

public void setEmail(String email){
    this.email = email;
}

@NotNull
@Column(nullable = false, length = 14)
public String getTelefone(){
    return telefone;
}

public void setTelefone(String telefone){
    this.telefone = telefone;
}

@NotNull
@Column(nullable = false, length = 14)
public String getCelular() {
    return celular;
}

public void setCelular(String celular) {
    this.celular = celular;
}

@NotNull
@Column(nullable = false, length = 200)
public String getEndereco(){
    return endereco;
}

public void setEndereco(String endereco){
    this.endereco = endereco;
}

@NotNull
@Column(nullable = false, length = 9)
public String getCep(){
    return cep;
}

public void setCep(String cep){
    this.cep = cep;
}

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "estado_sigla")
public Estado getEstado(){
    return estado;
}

public void setEstado(Estado estado){
    this.estado = estado;
}

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "cidadeNome")
public Cidade getCidade() {
    return cidade;
}

public void setCidade(Cidade cidade) {
    this.cidade = cidade;
}

@NotNull
@Column(nullable = false, length = 7)
public String getStatus() {
    return status;
}

public void setStatus(String status) {
    this.status = status;
}

@Override
public int hashCode() {
    final int prime = 31;
    int result = 1;
    result = prime * result + ((id == null) ? 0 : id.hashCode());
    return result;
}

@Override
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    if (this == obj)
        return true;
    if (obj == null)
        return false;
    if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
        return false;
    Usuario other = (Usuario) obj;
    if (id == null) {
        if (other.id != null)
            return false;
    } else if (!id.equals(other.id))
        return false;
    return true;
}

@ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinTable(name = "usuario_grupo", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name="usuario_id"),
        inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "grupo_id"))
public List<Grupo> getGrupos() {
    return grupos;
}

public void setGrupos(List<Grupo> grupos) {
    this.grupos = grupos;
}

}
```

**UsuariosRep.java**

```
public class UsuariosRep implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
@Inject
private EntityManager manager;

public Usuario guardar(Usuario usuario) {
    EntityTransaction trx = manager.getTransaction();

    trx.begin();

    usuario = manager.merge(usuario);

    trx.commit();

    return usuario;
}

/*public Usuario porNome(String nome) 
{
    return manager.find(Usuario.class, nome);
}*/

public Usuario porNome(String nome) {
    Usuario usuario = null;

    try{
    usuario = this.manager.createQuery("from Usuario where lower(nome) = :nome", Usuario.class)
            .setParameter("nome", nome.toLowerCase()).getSingleResult();
    }catch (NoResultException e){
        // Nenhum usuario encontrado com o nome informado.
    }
    return usuario;
}

public Usuario porId(Long id)
{
    return manager.find(Usuario.class, id);
}

public List<Usuario> listaDeUsu() 
{
    return manager.createQuery("from Usuario", Usuario.class).getResultList();
}

public List<Usuario> raizes()
{
    return  manager.createQuery("from Usuario",Usuario.class).getResultList(); 
}

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public List<Usuario> filtrados(UsuarioFilter filtro) {

    Session session = manager.unwrap(Session.class);

    Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(Usuario.class);

    if (filtro.getNome() != "") 
    {
        System.out.println(filtro.getNome());
        criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("nome", filtro.getNome()));
    }

    if (filtro.getStatus() != null)
    {
        criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("status", filtro.getStatus()));
    }

    // orderBy do SQL
    return criteria.addOrder(Order.asc("id")).list();
}

public void remover(Usuario usuario) {
    this.manager.remove(usuario);
    EntityTransaction trx = manager.getTransaction();
    trx.begin();
    manager.flush();
    trx.commit();
}

public Usuario porEmail(String email) {
    Usuario usuario = null;

    try{
        usuario = this.manager.createQuery("from Usuario where lower(email) = :email", Usuario.class)
                .setParameter("email", email.toLowerCase()).getSingleResult();
    }
    catch (NoResultException e){
        FacesUtil.addErrorMessage("Nenhum usuário encontrado");
    }
    return usuario;
}
}
```

**AppUserDetailService.java**

```
public class AppUserDetailsService implements UserDetailsService{


@Override
public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String email) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
    UsuariosRep usuariosRep = CDIServiceLocator.getBean(UsuariosRep.class);
    Usuario usuario = usuariosRep.porEmail(email);
    UsuarioSistema user = null;

    if(usuario != null){
        user = new UsuarioSistema(usuario, getGrupos(usuario));
    }
    return user;
}


private Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> getGrupos(Usuario usuario) {
    List<SimpleGrantedAuthority> authorities = new ArrayList<>();

    for(Grupo grupo : usuario.getGrupos()){
        authorities.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority(grupo.getNome().toUpperCase()));
    }

    return authorities;
}

}
```

**UsuarioSistema.java**

```
//a classe User pertence ao Spring Security
public class UsuarioSistema extends User {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
private Usuario usuario;

public UsuarioSistema(Usuario usuario, Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> authorities) {
    super(usuario.getEmail(), usuario.getSenha(), authorities);
    this.usuario = usuario;
}

public Usuario getUsuario() {
    return usuario;
}
}
```

Para encurtar os códigos, retirei algumas linhas iniciais como a parte dos imports.

Caso esteja faltado algum arquivo, por favor me avisem para que possa acrescentá-los imediatamente.

Agradeço a todas as opiniões e sugestões postadas.

Answer (score 0):

Pelo que entendi do seu sistema, você teria que fazer uma alteração na sua classe `AppUserDetailService.java`, inserindo a condição do `status`. Faça uma verificação caso o `usuario` retorne diferente de `null` e caso o `status` seja seja igual a `ativo`, assim: `usuario.getStaus().equals("ativo")`. Então ficaria desta forma:

```
if(usuario != null){
     if(usuario.getStaus().equals("ativo")){
          user = new UsuarioSistema(usuario, getGrupos(usuario));
     }
}
```

Ou você pode colocar no mesmo `if` usando  `&&` que seria equivalente:

```
if(usuario != null && usuario.getStaus().equals("ativo")){
     user = new UsuarioSistema(usuario, getGrupos(usuario));
}
```